# Connecting frontend with backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

I am creating a react native app that needs to perform registering and authentication of users. I am able to make a POST request that talks to a mongoose server and saves the information in MongoDB. What I want to do now is that when a user inputs their username, email, and password into a textbox screen in React, I want this informaiton to be savedin my MongoDB database. I am having trouble connecting the frontend (React Native) with the backend (MongoDB database).

Here is the code for my register screen of my React Native App:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./styles";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import router from "../../../../../backend/routes/auth";

function RegisterScreen(props) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.container}
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
    >
      <View style={styles.jellyContainer}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="jellyfish" size={60} color="black" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          nativeID="usernameInput"
          placeholder="Username"
          value={username}
          onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        ></TextInput>
        <TextInput
          nativeID="nameInput"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={name}
          onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        ></TextInput>
        <TextInput
          nativeID="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        ></TextInput>
        <TextInput
          nativeID="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={Password}
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          style={styles.input}
          secureTextEntry
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => router.post("/register/...")}//where json is input text fields, should I be calling an APi request here to register?
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

export default RegisterScreen;
```

Here is auth.js, where I have a POST request, where a user should be able to register, in addition to other API requests...

```js
const express = require("express");
const UserDao = require("../data/UserDao");
const { checkAdmin } = require("../util/permissions");
const { verifyPassword } = require("../util/hashing");
const { createToken, verifyToken } = require("../util/token");

const router = express.Router();
const users = new UserDao();

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    const data = await users.create({
      username,
      email,
      password,
      role: "CLIENT",
    });
    res.status(201).json({ data });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});

router.post("/authenticate", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (!username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "You must provide both username/email and password.",
    });
  }

  try {
    const user = await users.readOne(username);
    const isAuthenticated = await verifyPassword(
      password,
      user ? user.password : ""
    );

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      return res.status(403).json({
        message: "Wrong username or password!",
      });
    } else {
      const token = createToken(user);
      return res.json({
        message: "Authentication successful!",
        token: token,
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(err.status || 500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});

router.post("/verify", async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;
  const isValid = await verifyToken(token);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      message: "Invalid or expired token!",
    });
  }

  return res.json({
    message: "Token verified, and it is valid!",
    token: token,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Finally, here is a screenshot of Postman, where I am able to test my API requests and you can see that I am able to get the correct output back of a user being successfully registered. Once this is successful, the new user is added to my MongoDB database.

[image]

Also, as you can see here, my new registered user has been added to my already established MongoDB collection

[image]

Any insight on how to allow input from my frontend to push information to my MongoDB database will be very helpful!

Comment: You wouldn't POST from your frontend using code from your backend. They are meant to be separate codebases running in separate environments. Run your backend locally and experiment with `fetch` or a library (Axios is the most common) to send your HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your front end needs to be making a call to the endpoint, not locally import the code from your backend.

What you're doing with postman is correct. Here is what you need to do in your front end:

```
const registerUser = async () => {
  try {
    let payload = {username, email, password}
    let response = fetch(`http://localhost:5050/register`, {
      'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
    let data = await response.json()
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
<TouchableOpacity
 onPress={() => registerUser()}
 style={styles.button}
>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful, would you recommend I use fwtch(0 or axios for HTTP requests?

Comment: Some people prefer Axios, it has some additional features. Truthfully, for most use cases, I haven't found a difference. I stick to fetch, so it's one less package I have bloating my app.